# Make Wordpress recovery password manual, not autogenerated

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing a problem with wordpress related with the new version, when a user wants to recover its password and click on the recovery mail, the password is autogenerated.

Is there any way to reset the password manually (like in other versions it was by default)?

I attach an example picture
[image: Autogenerated password]

Comment: Never noticed this change, so an admin can't set the password for another user anymore?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks like on my local 4.3 install:

[image: password reset]

where it's possible to manually reset the password.

Note that if we disable javascript, it will show up like this:

[image: no javascript]

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple.

1. Open up the wp-login.php in wordpress FTP directory
2. Search for `data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_generate_password( 16 ) ); ?>"`
3. Remove the php section, so the source is going to look like this: `data-pw=""`
4. Save

This should solve your problem.